# what assembly use to create Table mapping in EntityFramework using EntityTypeConfiguration

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I try to create table mapping with EnityFramework code first. I need to drive from this base class EntityTypeConfiguration but I am not able to find the assembly. I already added the EntityFramework.

This is my code:

```
     using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
     namespace Domain.Repository.Configuration
  {
  public class TypeMap : EntityTypeConfiguration
   {

    public TypeMap()
    {
        // Table Mapping

    }
 }
}
```

EntityTypeConfiguration is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespace:  System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration
Assembly:  EntityFramework (in EntityFramework.dll)

See this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696117%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

Comment: Make sure you really downloaded and included EntityFramework in your working project. Then make sure that intellisense shows you hints when writing typing System.Data.Model.Entity and ModelConfiguration. Then build your solution. May be it will help.